# Is display:flex inherited?

Tags: html, css, flexbox

I have this code. I gave my body a `display:flex`. Now, shouldn't all child elements become flex items, being inside the body and the body is 1. a flex container and 2. a wrapper for all the children?

So I tried looking through the developer's tools inside Firefox: `align-items`/ `justify-content` has no effect on this element since it’s neither a flex container nor a grid container.

Please explain to me when I need to give each div, section, main, a `display:flex` on it is own and when it is automatically inherited.

Here is my code:

```
#html 
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css">
    <title>Butterfly Music App</title>
</head>

<body>
    <main>

    </main>
    <footer>

    </footer>
</body>

</html>
```

```
#css
html, body {
    height: 100%;
}
body {
    display: flex;
    flex-direction: column;
    background-color: cyan;
    font-family: gabriola;
    color: purple;
}
footer {
    justify-content: flex-end;
    align-items: flex-start;
    flex: 0 0 120px;
    background-color: pink;
}
```

Comment: display is not an inherited property (whataver the situation or the value)

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The `display` property is not inherited, so `display: flex` is not either. See the following pages for more info:

- https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/display (MDN)
- https://www.w3schools.com/cssref/pr_class_display.asp (W3Schools)